# Bevel vertices on a flat subdivided plane

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm trying something that I managed before, but not anymore.

I have a subdiveded **flat** plane (which represents a grid) where I want to make a few more holes (see picture one).

If I select the vertices and then do  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, I don't get rounded corners but straight (see picture two).

My question is what am I doing wrong?

I'm using Blender 2.79, and I'm a beginner.

[image: picture one]
[image: picture two]

Comment: are you referring to picture #3? All the settings can be tweaked in the Operator box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.79 (or 2.9), I don't think you can have it in one step.

You can extrude along Z <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, bevel the corner edges <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, delete the extrusion <kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: That's one way to fix it. I have now copied and pasted the relevant vertices where I needed them, then deleted the faces and then cleared the mesh of doubles and the loose ones.